# Replace special character in string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm having a issue with a problem where I want to replace a special character in a text-file that I have created with a string that I defined.

```
"""
This is a guess the number game.
"""
import datetime, random
from random import randint

fileOpen = open('text.txt','r')
savedData = fileOpen.read()
fileOpen.close()
#print (savedData)

now = datetime.datetime.now()
date = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
date = str(date)
#print(date)
time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
time = str(time)
#print(time)


savedData.replace(";", date)
print (savedData)
```

I have tried with something that looks like this. I thought I could just read from the file, save it's content in my own string and then use the `replace` function to alter the string.
But when I try to do the last print, noting has happened with the `saveData` string. What am I doing wrong?

The text-file just looks like this, all is on one line:

```
Today it's the ; and the time is (. I'm feeling ) and : is todays lucky number. The unlucky number of today is #
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) doesn't alter the string in place, no string operations do because *strings are immutable*. It returns a copy of the replaced string which you need to assign to another name:

```
replacedData = savedData.replace(";", date)
```

now your replaced string will be saved to the new name you specified in the assignment.

Comment: Ah ofc!
Thanks for the fast answer :)